# How to skip updating data of a particular table from django initial_data.json file on each south migration?

Tags: json, django, migration, django-south

I have a **initial_data.json** file in my project which is loaded to the database initialy using syncdb.
Now every time when i migrate(south migration) the app, old initial_data gets updated in the table.
I dont want every tables to get updated again, since some of the columns in the table are modified by user. I need to skip those tables,any solutions.

Comment: Guys, i have'nt found any proper solution for this problem yet. Some methods i came to know are 1)Use serialize to fetch current db data and remove it from the json file after comparing or else 2)Remove the particular table's entire data from json file using read and write operation.